# Testcafe unable to filter <tspan> using Selector.withText()

Tags: svg, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, tspan

I'm trying to filter elements on the `svg` diagram using selector: `Selector('.joint-type-mapping-record .v-line').withText('testElement')`. But in a result a got a message, that give element not found in DOM.

I checked that innerText is available for `<tspan>` and it isn't. Then I tried to add customDOMProperties (`addCustomDOMProperties({ innerText: (el) => el.innerText });`), but got error: `1) TypeError: Cannot redefine property: innerText`

Is any way to handle `<tspan>` using `withText()`?

Here the page code:

```html
<g model-id="6c1b0506-321a-4c27-8a06-7f2bfa5851ed" data-type="mapping.Record" id="j_488" class="joint-cell joint-type-mapping joint-type-mapping-record joint-element joint-theme-default" magnet="false" transform="translate(-171,99)">
<text joint-selector="headerLabel" id="v-11781" font-size="20" xml:space="preserve" font-family="Galano Grotesque" font-weight="500" text-anchor="middle" text-vertical-anchor="middle" fill="#333333" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,109,15)">
<tspan dy="0.3em" class="v-line">testElement</tspan></text></g>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TestCafe doesn't search for HTML elements inside an svg element by default. You can use a selector [initialized](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/selector/constructor.html#initialize-selectors) with a client function for this purpose. Take a look at the following example:

```js
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `New Fixture`
    .page `https://xg35y.csb.app/`;

test('New Test', async t => {
    const getVlineElement = Selector(() => {
        const allVlineElements = document.querySelectorAll('.joint-type-mapping-record .v-line');

        return [].slice.call(allVlineElements)
            .filter(tspan => tspan.textContent === 'testElement')[0];
    });

    await t
        .expect(Selector(getVlineElement).textContent).eql('testElement');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, @aleks-pro for your answer. It works for me. Could you explain why you call Selector for `const getVlineElement` and then inside `t.expect`?

Comment: Looks like a typo. I think it is not necessary to wrap the `getVlineElement` selector in the Selector function one more time.